# Use year and month of a datetime column as a Table key

Tags: sql, database-design

Relatively inexperienced SQL user here.  What I'd like to do is only have one entry per month of each year.  Is there a way to use datetime like this in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `month` and a `year` column, and a unique index on `(year, month)`.  For example:

```
create unique index UX_YourTable_YearMonth on YourTable(year, month)
```

Answer (score 1):

I definitely would store that in a single Date/Time field, where you could store the date as the 1st of the month.
You can easily turn a date into the 1st of month using `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0)`

The advantage of using a Date field is that it will make **grouping** easier for reporting on any timeframe (Bi monhly, quarterly...) using most report tools, like Excel Pivot, Access, SQL Server Reporting services...

Answer (score 0):

You could if your date would always have the same day and time being inserted. For example if your dates always looked like `mm/01/yyyy 12:00:00` this would work. However I doubt your dates will be like this. I suggest making the key be on two seaparate columns `month, year`

Answer (score 0):

It's best *not* to use a datetime or timestamp for this. Instead, use separate columns for year and month. Use CHECK() constraints to keep the values sane. If your dbms doesn't enforce CHECK() constraints (MySQL, for example), create additional tables for valid years and valid months, and set foreign key references to them.

```
create table your_table_name (
  year integer not null check (year between 2000 and 2050),
  month integer not null check (month between 1 and 12),
  -- Other columns go here.
  primary key (year, month)
);
```